# MD5 hash differs between JS and shell

Tags: encryption, sh

I'm trying to generate a base64-encoded MD5 hash.

In Javascript, I have:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const utf8 = require('utf8');

const hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
const bodyData = JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello world' });

hash.update(utf8.encode(bodyData)).digest('base64');
```

resulting in:

```
jANzQ+rgAHyf1MWQFSwvYw==
```

Attempting to do the same in the shell, I have:

```sh
echo -n '{"message":"Hello world"}' \
    | iconv -t utf-8 \
    | md5sum \
    | cut -d' ' -f1 \
    | base64
```

resulting in:

```
OGMwMzczNDNlYWUwMDA3YzlmZDRjNTkwMTUyYzJmNjMK
```

What am I missing? Why do I get a different result than I got using Javascript?

Comment: Try `xxd -r -p | base64` instead of `base64`

Comment: @Topaco: You should put that an answer with an explanation

Comment: It's sort of offtopic, but why are you using MD5 in 2021? Even SHA1 is not secure and collision-resistant anymore.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky I'm using MD5 as part of a signed request mechanism that a third-party requires. https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice/api-reference/authentication/#application-signed-request

Comment: Okay, they should have a reason for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NodeJS code returns the *Base64* encoded MD5 hash, while [`md5sum`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/md5sum.htm) returns the *hex* encoded MD5 hash, which is then Base64 encoded because of the following [`base64`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/base64.htm).

To achieve the result of the NodeJS code, the hex encoded hash must first be hex decoded prior to the Base64 encoding.

This is possible with [`xxd -r -p`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/xxd.htm). Overall:

```
echo -n '{"message":"Hello world"}' | iconv -t utf-8 | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1 | xxd -r -p | base64
```

with the output:

```
jANzQ+rgAHyf1MWQFSwvYw==
```

Comment: I found that `openssl md5 -binary` works as well: `echo -n '{"message":"Hello world"}' | iconv -t utf-8 | openssl md5 -binary | base64`

Comment: @ivan - Works also. There are several ways to determine the MD5 hash depending on what is available in the particular environment, [`openssl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl.html) is just another option besides  [`md5sum`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/md5sum.htm).